# Getting value using key returns null despite existing

Tags: php

I have these 4 var dumps :

```
function test($id) {
    $arr = $this->c;
    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($arr);
    var_dump($arr[$id]);
    var_dump(isset($arr[$id]));
}
```

Returning respectively :

```
int(193558)

array(1) {
  [193538]=>
  array(2) {
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}

NULL

bool(false)
```

So the key actually exists inside the array, but weirdly trying to get it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: 1935*5*8 is different from 1935*3*8

Comment: @msg yes I didn't notice that silly mistake. Thanks ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `193558 != 193538`.

Comment: Oops I didn't even notice the ids were different, stupid me, thanks!